# Issue in zoom in and zoomout of highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

In highchart, After zoomin, if I zoomout  an additional series being added [Initial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4v08.png),  [After zoomin and zoomout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/touQp.png). Highchart is being used with react version 16.7. This is the basic linechart configuration from highcharts website.

```
      chart: {
        zoomType: "x"
      },
      title: {
        text: ""
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: "datetime"
      },
      plotOptions: {
        line: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          },
          threshold: 80,
          negativeColor: "#9ACD32"
        },
        series: {
          lineWidth: 1
        }
      },

      series: [
        {
          name: label,
          color: "#D98C0C",
          data: data,
          zoneAxis: "x",
          zones: [
            {
              value: startTime,
              dashStyle: "solid",
              color: "#00ff21"
            },
            {
              value: stopTime,
              dashStyle: "solid",
              color: "#ff6634"
            },
            {
              dashStyle: "solid",
              color: "#00ff21"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: You should show your code

Comment: Hi @Partha Sarathi Nanda, Do you use some wrapper for React? I have tested your chart options and they work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wqy5bk2t/ Please reproduce your problem in some online code editor, for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-j1b25

Comment: yes i use a wrapper